# Baseline Profile - variants effect in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, production-environment, build-variant, baseline-profile

In my current project, I just can build non-prod variants base on my company's policy and I currently want to apply Baseline profile for the Prod version. So I wonder that when I generate a baseline profile in non-prod environment and put the profile under main folder, will it effect for the Prod version?

Hope to see answers for this question

Answer (score 1):

If you put the generated profile into `src/main/baselineProfile` (or formerly `src/main/baseline-prof.txt`) then it will be correctly used in the prod version of your app.

Be aware that if the prod version has some custom code paths that can't be exercised with the generator, than you may be missing some potential improvement. Ideally you want to have the non-prod version as close as possible to the prod one.

But as with other improvements, you can start with something and iterate on it to squeeze even more improvements.